# Creating a file with date and time as file name using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Why can't I use this code block to create the file? It keeps giving an OS Error

```
from datetime import datetime
D = datetime.now()
name = str(D)+".txt"
file = open(name,"w+")
```

Comment: Can we see the `OSError` you're getting? It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datetime.now() returns a string like this "2020-04-28 19:24:55.738095". Im not sure about it but as far as i know most operation systems dont allow ":" in filenames. I was able to solve the issue by doing the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
D = datetime.now()
D = str(D).replace(":", "-")
name = D + ".txt"
with open(name, "w") as file:
    file.write("any data")
```